# Renaming photos on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

How can I name photos on iPhone ?

I wonder if there is a way to rename them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to add notes to photos. I use `Google Keep`, I add photos and make notes to them.

My earlier solution :

I email them and add a note.